# Ansible not piking up changes in inventory/hosts file

Tags: ansible

I have an Ansible Playbook and a few hundred hosts in the `inventory/hosts` and I can run the Playbook and everything works fine, no issues.

But I noticed if I made any changes to the `inventory/hosts` file it seems to keep going through all the old entries that used to be in there and are not there any more. Is there some type of caching mechanism that is on by default? If so, is it possible to turn it off?

If I actually use the `-i inventory/hosts` file, it seems to work fine. Even though if I run the Playbook like so its still should be using the same `inventory/hosts` file.

ansible-playbook info.yaml

Answer (score 2):

`inventory/hosts` in the current directory is **not** the default inventory if you ommit it on the ansible-playbook command line (unless you configured it in ansible.cfg).

The default inventory is usually `/etc/ansible/hosts`. You can easily see the default inventory (and if a config file is used) by running `ansible-playbook -v my_playbook.yml` (no other options) and looking at the first output lines.

My guess is that your are modifying an inventory which is not the one you use.

Regarding your question about cache, there are cache mechanisms that can be used for facts and dynamic inventories but they must be specifically enabled and configured (e.g. installing redis, giving path to a cache file...).

Comment: You are correct in saying that it looks at the default inventory/hosts which is located in /etc/ansible/hosts but i just cat that file and nothing is in there, except some samples which are all commented out and i just ran the -v option and i see that its looking at the correct inventory/hosts file

Comment: Did you notice it is using an ansible.cfg file when running with -v ? Are there any cache mechanisms configured in there ?

Comment: Just checked that and no caching mechanisms are enabled.

Comment: Sorry but I'm out of ideas on this one. You should run with -vvv to have full debugging and look carefully at the output. You will hopefully find some info so solve you issue.

Comment: Yeah im stuck on this too, i tried the -vvv but same thing, it shows its using the correct inventory/hosts, which is weird, because if i use -i inventory/hosts it works, which doesn't make any sense